# If current consumption of serial flash SST26VF064B is 15mAq104MHZ then at 50MHZ it is 7.5?

Tags: microcontroller, current, serial, microchip, flash

I am Mohan working in Germany. For my data logger project i choose SST26VF064B serial flash. My data logger should consume lowest power possible. I see that SST26VF064B is consuming 15mA@104MHZ. In my project I use upto 2MHZ or 5MHZ frequency to the serial flash. My question is if it consumes 15mA at 104MHZ then howmuch it consumes at 2MHZ and 5MHZ?. 
Does it consumes 7.5mA at 52MHZ? Is it directly praportional?.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the datasheet

[image: SST26V current consumption]

The read currents at different speeds are noted and they are clearly not an ordinary linear curve.

When the interface is idle (no reads or writes active) then the current consumption is 45μA max.

The total current consumed is (assuming no writes for now) Read current * duty cycle of reads (what percentage of the time are reads being performed) + standby current * 1 / duty cycle.

The write current does not change with interface speed (see the datasheet for details).

If you are doing writes and reads, then add the average write current to the average read current and add the average standby current.

As those averages are use-specific, I cannot help any further.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The write current does not change with interface speed (see the datasheet for details). I dont find this in data sheet. Can you tell me pg.no. Thank you.

Comment: So it looks like there will only be marginal overall energy savings for lower-speed operation, since those writes and reads will take longer. If you can reduce the number of RW events or their frequency, that will have the most energy savings. Buffer several values if you can, and write a block of them at once, then idle the interface for as long as possible.

Comment: Yes.I also planning to send data to buffer and then to serial flash.

Comment: I have a doubt that in every datasheet i see only read currents but not wtite currents why?. For my project we dont care about read currents bcoz that were done while my device connected to PC. write currents are done when device run with a battery hence write currents should be less. unfortunatly i dont find write currents. I can not order all serial flash devices and test. Usually how will be the writing currents? less than reading? also depends on clock speed? and size of data we are sending?.Thank you.